# How to run mod_php and fastcgi side-by-side?

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi, mod-php

Is it possible to run certain PHP scripts through `mod_php` when your apache server is configured to run as FastCGI? (FPM/FastCGI).
This could be configured at the directory level, but I'm not sure what syntax to use in the apache configuration.

Server OS: Ubuntu-Server 11.04

Comment: As far as I know, if you're looking for directory level granularity, you'll have to use mod_proxy (and friends) to accomplish this setup: `<Location />
ProxyPass http://localhost:1337/
ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:1337/
</Location>` This example uses ports, instead of the default FPM configuration that uses PID's... so you'll have to do the rest of the research. :P